# How to get connected iPhone IP address through mac terminal

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, mobile, automation

Is there any way to get IP address of connected iPhone through mac terminal ?

I'm facing following problem:

I have connected iPhone device with mac machine, now i want to get the connected iPhone device IP address (Device connected with WiFi) through mac terminal.

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal and type

```
arp -a
```

I found the command on this thread 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3548204?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Without SSH and a jailbreaked device, I can't see how this is possible. Can you explain more of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want connected device IP address to run automation on the device through terminal. Is there any way to get the IP without jailbrake.(For ex. I can get the device UDID through terminal same like that I want IP address of the device)

Comment: You can get the UUID that the device registers when connecting via USB but nothing else right? How do you read the UUID?